# Keeping the focus on the flagged content when purging comments under a post

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

## Bug - Keeping the focus on the flagged content when purging comments under a post

For example:

When purging all the comments under a too many comments flag, or too many answers flag (it probably does this for all posts) all the comments disappear (deleted) and it causes the box with the flagged post to jump up the screen - as the div height is drastically reduced. This means scrolling up to find the post to mark the flag as done.

Example:

View before purging comments:

[image]

After purge:

[image]

The flagged post when I found it after the purge - as the flag hasn't been handled.

[image]

Can we somehow keep the UI focused on the actual box that we're dealing with until the flag is dismissed?

On a web browser, large screen.

Comment: Are you using a user script? That "purge all" button isn't one of mine.  When you purge all through vanilla UI (in the moderator menu) it shows all the deleted comments rather than hiding them.

Comment: @BrianNickel I use 45 user scripts :/

Comment: Marking as no-repro since this is coming from a user script.  The script could call `.scrollIntoView()` on the comment list or post if they wanted to keep it on screen after the action completes.

Comment: Thanks @BrianNickel I am gradually going through them